# $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic to its quotient by $D^2$ (closed disc).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to show what is written in the title. I've used the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $f(x)=\frac{||x||-1}{||x||}x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D^2$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, which I've proved to be continuous and surjective. I only need to show that this map is closed, but I've got problems to do it.

I tried to do it considering a closed set $C\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and a sequence $\{y_n\}\subset f(C)$ converging to some $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, I've got a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset C$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$, but I don't know whether this sequence converges or not, I only know that $f(x_n)\to y=f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: Are the $x_n$ necessarily bounded?

Comment: I don't know. Are they? If they were I could find a convergent subsequence necessarily converging to $x$, and that would solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I guess they have to be bounded because $\frac{||x_n||-1}{||x||}x_n$ converges to $y$.

Comment: The closed unit disk is not homeomorphic to the plane, since one is compact and the other is not.

Comment: You mean you identify $D^2$ to a point?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that if $y=f(x)$ and $\|x\|>1$,
then $x=\frac{\|y\|+1}{\|y||}y$,
which shows that the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus D^2$ has a continuous inverse $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus D^2$.
That should take care of the case $y\ne0$.

If $y=0$, your sequence $(x_n)$ will satisfy $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|x_n\|\le1$,
so you can find a convergent subsequence whose limit $x$ satisfies $\|x\|\le1$, and you're done!